# Reuse a "No" from game assets

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm trying to reuse a recording of a "No" response with an NPC that is set to the voice type "Male Sly".

Currently, I have a dialog fragment script that calls:

```
myQuest.showLocalChest(akSpeakerRef)
```

The myQuest variable is correctly cast as my own quest-script and the called method does this:

```
akSpeakerRef.say(Topic_No)
```

Where Topic_No is initialized to FreeformWindhelmANO.

---

What I'm asking about is how can I find a simple "No" response among the hundreds of Topic forms (that will work for any of the default voice types)?

If that's too complex, I'd settle for a simple example that uses the `say()` method of `ObjectReference` in a successful way.

Comment: Why not just record it? Recycled voice assets rarely work well.

Comment: This is not a question for http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: Aside, if what you're needing is to find the *audio* file, the tool you want is TES5dump: dump out all the dialog records to a text file and search for a "no" from the right actor type. (It's hard to tell from the question if that's quite the problem.)

Comment: This is best asked on the Besthsoft [Creation Kit subforum](http://forums.bethsoft.com/forum/184-the-creation-kit/). That's where the real experts are.